# redis,set a value to 3,but its type is string

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redis-server

I use redis 6.2.4,in the redis-cli i input command:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set k5 3
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> type k5
string
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

why the type of `k5` is string but not number?

Comment: check redis types, there s no number as type ->  https://redis.io/topics/data-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number` is not a Redis (data) type.

I'm adding some links for your reference:

- [TYPE command](https://redis.io/commands/type)
- [Redis data types in brief](https://redis.io/topics/data-types)
- [Introduction to Redis data types](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro)

---

[OBJECT ENCODING](https://redis.io/commands/object) command may suit your need.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set k5 3
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> OBJECT ENCODING k5
"int"
```